# Rekey smart lock for 2 keys

Tags: doors, lock

We are using smart locks. We need Tenant key and office master key to operate lock. Is this possible and how?

Comment: How could we possibly know? You haven't even told us what hardware we're talking about. Please revise your post to add enough detail for answers.

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring to Weiser's "SmartKeyⓇ" technology, it can't be done.

These mechanisms are designed to be very easily rekeyable, but to accomplish this they had to use a non-conventional pin system, and it can work with only one key.

To get around this obvious deficiency, they have recently invented a lock with two separate cylinders.
A large outer cylinder be rotated to switch the two inner cylinders between the active and unused positions.

To me, it looks like something Al Jaffee would have thought of, or maybe a mini Rube Goldberg device:

[image]

— [SmartKey Re-Key Technology | Smart Alternative to Master Keying](http://www.weiserlock.com/en/products/productseries/smartkey/keycontrol)